# Cannot upload a featured image in page

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I have to add a featured image to my WordPress homepage, so when i share the site the thumbnail will appear. So far so good, but when i paste this to my template:

```
 <div class="entry-thumbnail">
    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } else {
            echo 'Template not exists';
        }
    ?>
 </div>
```

Before that i'm uploading the image i want and i got this:

[image]

After var_dump to the

```
the_post_thumbnail
```

i got "null" result. I've tried to add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )` but it's not working. Any ideas why i can't upload a featured image to my page ?

Comment: Your code for displaying thumbnails looks fine. Your problem seems to be when you insert an image into the page, since it should show the image you uploaded, not that "missing" icon. Check the link of the image. Where does it point to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give image src for the image for ex:

```
       <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
```